# Setting dust jacket parameters using bookcover given a dust jacket template from printer

Tags: publishing, bookcover

The following is a dust jacket template from the printer that I'm trying to follow using the `bookcover` package:

[image]

The numbers in the template don't seem to add up between the 20mm wrap around, safety margin, flap width, and spine, for example.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[
    coverwidth = 216mm,
    coverheight = 279mm,
    spinewidth = 11mm,
    bleedwidth  = 20mm,
    marklength  = 20mm,
    flapwidth = 80mm,
    wrapwidth = 3mm
%    trimmed % Show only trimmed part!
    ]{bookcover}

\letnamebookcoverpart{xspine}{spine}[0mm,0mm,0mm,0mm]
% The 'xspine' is an arbitrary name, which is the trimmed part of the spine.
% [<left margin>,<top margin>,<right margin>,<bottom margin>] deductions for margins
\letnamebookcoverpart{xfront}{front}[0mm,0mm,0mm,0mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{xback}{back}[0mm,0mm,0mm,0mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{xfrontflap}{front flap}[0mm,0mm,0mm,0mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{xbackflap}{back flap}[0mm,0mm,0mm,0mm]

% Used for title on the spine
\newbookcovercomponenttype{center rotate}{
    \vspace{0.5in}
    \centering
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{#1}
    \vfill}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{bookcover}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xspine}
color=lightgray
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xfront}
color=lightgray
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xback}
color=lightgray
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xfrontflap}
color=lightgray
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xbackflap}
color=lightgray
\end{bookcoverelement}

% Picture on the front cover behind the title
\begin{bookcoverelement}{center}{bg front}[-2.5in,-2.35in,,-1.138in]
    \resizebox{2in}{!}{\includegraphics{CoverImage.png}}
\end{bookcoverelement}

% Title on the front cover
\begin{bookcoverelement}{normal}{front}[,,,1in]
    \centering
    \bfseries
    \resizebox{7in}{!}{MY CATCHY}\\[8mm]
    \resizebox{7in}{!}{TITLE}\\
\end{bookcoverelement}

% Author on the front cover
\begin{bookcoverelement}{normal}{front}[4.75in,,,9.5in]
    \centering
    \bfseries
    \resizebox{2.6739in}{!}{Author One}\\[3.7083mm]
    \resizebox{2.6739in}{!}{Author Two}\\
\end{bookcoverelement}

% Title on the spine
\begin{bookcoverelement}{center rotate}{spine}
    \LARGE\bfseries
    \scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\textit{\textrm{My Catchy Title}}}
\end{bookcoverelement}

\end{bookcover}

\end{document}
```

Where is the 20mm wrap around in the template and how to account for it?  Is everything in light blue a 5mm safety margin? What is the dark grey measurement and how to account for it?

It seems to me that, from left to right, we should have that 619mm = 20mm + 5mm + 80mm + 5mm + dark grey + 5mm + 216mm + 5mm + 11mm + 5mm + 216mm + 5mm + dark grey + 5mm + 80mm + 5mm + 20mm, but this doesn't add up for any choice of dark grey.

Comment: Is the finished size the dimension of the white front? How was 291mm calculated?

Comment: @hair-splitter The final book size is 279mm x 216mm so it's a standard US Letter size.  The 291mm and 619mm sizes are what is confusing me.  I would think that 291mm is supposed to be 279mm plus safety margin plus wrap around but that doesn't add up.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    coverwidth  = 226mm, % 216mm + 2x5mm
    coverheight = 289mm, % 279mm + 2x5mm
    spinewidth  = 11mm,
    bleedwidth  = 20mm,
    marklength  = 0mm,
    flapwidth   = 90mm, % 80mm + 2x5mm
    wrapwidth   = 3mm
    ]{bookcover}

\letnamebookcoverpart{xspine}{spine}[,5mm,,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{xfront}{front}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{xback}{back}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{xfrontflap}{front flap}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{xbackflap}{back flap}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]

\definecolor{bleed}{RGB}{124,180,225}
\definecolor{margin}{RGB}{173,209,236}
\definecolor{wrap}{RGB}{90,103,120}
\definecolor{spine}{RGB}{234,243,251}

\begin{document}

\begin{bookcover}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{bg whole}
color=bleed
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{whole}
color=margin
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xspine}
color=spine
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xfront}
color=white
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xback}
color=white
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xfrontflap}
color=white
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xbackflap}
color=white
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{back wrap}
color=wrap
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{front wrap}
color=wrap
\end{bookcoverelement}

\end{bookcover}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I run your code:  `! Package calc Error: `t' invalid at this point.`  It's pointing to line 98 in the bookcover.cls file:  `\ifdim\flapwidth>0pt\setlength{\wrapwidth}{\bookcover@wrapwidth}\fi`  I don't get the error when I set the `flapwidth` to 0mm.

Comment: I use TeX Live 2023, and this code works fine.